# Can I animate an NSBezierPath within a CALayer?

Tags: cocoa, core-animation, quartz-graphics

I have read the Core Animation Cook Book and Core Animation Programming Guide from Apple, but I'm not quite sure about some of the details.

Do I always have to animate a complete CALayer, or can I animate stuff within a CALayer?

If I have drawn a NSBezierPath within a layer and I want to animate/move this to another position, how do I do that?  Is there an example of this that you could point me to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, you do animate the CALayer as a whole for best performance.  If all you're looking to do is to shift the position of your Bezier path, you can simply animate the `position` or `frame` properties of your CALayer.

If you want to change the shape of a vector path, I'd recommend looking at the new CAShapeLayer, where you can animate between one CGPath and another by using the `path` property on the layer.  Joe Ricioppo has some sample code you can look at for this [here](http://tumbljack.com/post/179975074/complex-interpolation-with-cashapelayer-free).

Beyond that, you'll need to redraw the layer if you want to update its contents, rather than its base properties like position, scale, rotation, etc.

Comment: So if I want to have multiple shapes and animate those independently (or grouped), the shapes should each be on their own CALayer and I would then animate each CALayer?

Comment: @Neigaard - Yes, that's what would be recommended.  Compositing of layers is far faster than redrawing them.  Think of how the old-time cartoon animators used to re-use cels so that they could produce shows under a limited budget.  On the Mac, you can have hundreds of these layers onscreen at once, and even on the original model iOS devices you could have 50 of them animating around at 30-60 FPS.